# How to fetch image from Database and parse it to Json

Tags: json, android-studio

I have my images on my PC that is stored in htdocs in xampp and the path("C:\xampp\htdocs\project\images\pic.jpg) of that image is in database. How will I parse it to Json and display it on ImageView in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

It is Cliente / Server architecture , you need some work but it is easy

First you need to create a php file to access your database and retrieve data

Then you make an HTTP request to the XAMPP ( consider using VOLLEY library ) to access the php file

After that you parse the JSON response to get your data

finnaly you display the image using Glide/Picasso library

Hope this help you

Good Luck

Comment: I already did this but the image still not showing. because I only have path of the image like this: "C:\xampp\htdocs\project\images\pic.jpg" in my database not the web URL for image. How can I show my images with this path?